# how to displace an image in python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have an image size 400*200.
I have a frame size 400* 300.

I want to put the image in the center of frame. That is my image cordinate (0,0) starts with the frame cordinates (0,50).

Comment: Which library are you using for the GUI ? We need more information to help you...

Comment: @Elenaher, I am using PI Library.

Answer (score 2):

```
frame= Image.new(image.mode, (400, 300))
frame.paste(image, (0, 50))
```

(`frame.paste(image, (0, 50), image)` if the image to be framed has a transparency mask you want to keep. And pass a third parameter to `Image.new` to set the background colour of the frame if the default isn't what you want.)