# displace an image vertically in matlab?

Tags: matlab

This image is in gray scale, i´ve already done a scanning to detect the first and the last pixels i would like to move to top, and put those points into an array but all i´ve gotten is two pixels displaced.

I've found this example [how to displace an image in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778300/how-to-displace-an-image-in-python) , and it could help here but dont know how to make the changes

Comment: what do you mean displace it vertically? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to move a part of the image that is in the middle to top

Comment: @JoseAvelar: post the code you have so far..

Comment: @Jose Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately this question is a bit short on details to be considered useful for this site. I'm thrilled that you got your answer, but the question as it stands now hold little to no value for future visitors and I will have to close it. You should review the [ask] and [faq] pages for information about how to ask questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the example is very clear. It says that first you have to make a new matrix of the size you want your image to be. and then copy all of your pixel values into the new matrix. this is simple and good if you are not bothered about space.

if you want 'inplace' shift then you have to do the followig: I'll give an example and i hope you can take up from there: 
suppose your image matrix is something like this:

`A(1:4,1:4)` =

```
0 0 0 0
0 1 2 3
0 4 5 6
```

and you want to get:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

then you can do:

```
A(1,:) = []; 
A(:,1) = [];
```

EDIT:
taking the previous example, if you dont want to decrease the size of your matrix then you can copy the elements in the following way:

```
A(1,1) = A(2,2);
A(1,2) = A(2,3);
A(1,3) = A(2,4);
```

i think you can clearly see the pattern of copying. 
you can put the similar logic in a loop and that's it.